# I use pip to install pyautogui, but it still points me "No module named pyautogui"

Tags: python-3.x

1. My **main.py** module needs to import:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import threading
import pyautogui
```

But when I run the **main.py** module, it shows:

```
./main.py: line 5: import: command not found
./main.py: line 6: import: command not found
./main.py: line 7: import: command not found
./main.py: line 8: import: command not found
./main.py: line 9: import: command not found
```

2. AND after I install `pip3 install pyautogui`; it successfully installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.9.35)
```

BUT when I run the main.py, it still shows:

```
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

Python 3.8.8

I think there is something wrong with the download location, but I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone faced the similar problem?

Comment: upgrade your pip using `pip install --upgrade pip` and then try to install pyautogui

Comment: @AnonymousCoder Yes, i've upgraded pip. the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running your code? I think you are running it as executable without specifying the python path. So your OS is executing the file as a shell script. If your file name is `code.py`, then you can run it as an executable file in Linux by first marking it as executable by user using this command: `chmod +x code.py` and then run using `./code.py`. But to do this you need to add your python path at the top as a shebang line. Also specify what encoding to use in the next line as follows.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You can find your python path using this command on Linux: `which python` or `which python3`. Or just simply run the code using `python code.py`. In my Linux, `python` is used for python 2 and `python3` is for python 3 so depending on your OS the command may change.

Comment: hi, i run my code on mac os terminal. where should i specify the python path?

Comment: The command in mac os is same I think. Just find python path by `which python` or `which python3` or you can simply run using `python <your file name>`.

Comment: i use the command to fird python path: ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3```